# $ Windows newline symbol in Python bytes regex

Tags: python, regex

`$` matches at the end of a line, which is defined as either the end of the string, or any location followed by a newline character.

However, the Windows newline flag contains two characters `'\r\n'`, how to make `'$'` recognize `'\r\n'` as a newline character in `bytes`?

Here is what I have:

```
# Python 3.4.2
import re

input = b'''
//today is a good day \r\n
//this is Windows newline style \r\n
//unix line style \n
...other binary data... 
'''

L = re.findall(rb'//.*?$', input, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
for item in L : print(item)
```

now the output is:

```
b'//today is a good day \r'
b'//this is Windows newline style \r'
b'//unix line style '
```

but the expected output is as follows:

```
the expected output:
b'//today is a good day '
b'//this is Windows newline style '
b'//unix line style '
```

Comment: The typical way to deal with it is not to deal with it: `open("file", 'r')` should convert all newlines to `\n` at read time. You shouldn't have `\r\n` in your string during your execution. How are you getting a Windows-style string in the first place?

Comment: because I can't find accurate encoding of text file, just have to open it in binary mode

Comment: If you don't have at least a little bit of a clue about the encoding, how do you  know what bytes will be used for `\r\n`?

Comment: it's easy, just get the infomation which interests me, change them, then write them back still in binary mode. it works fine at least so far I found no problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to redefine anchor behavior.

To match a `//` with any number of characters other than CR and LF after it, use a negated character class `[^\r\n]` with `*` quantifier:

```
L = re.findall(rb'//[^\r\n]*', input)
```

Note that this approach does not require using `re.M` and `re.S` flags.

Or, you can add `\r?` before a `$` and enclose this part in a positive look-ahead (also, you will beed a `*?` lazy quantifier with `.`):

```
rb'//.*?(?=\r?$)'
```

The point in using a lookahead is that `$` itself is a kind of a lookahead since it does not really consume the `\n` character. Thus, we can safely put it into a look-ahead with optional `\r`.

Maybe this is not that pertinent since it is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx), but I think it is the same for Python:

> Note that `$` matches `\n` but does not match `\r\n` (the combination of carriage return and newline characters, or `CR/LF`). To match the `CR/LF` character combination, include `\r?$` in the regular expression pattern.

In PCRE, you can use [(*ANYCRLF), (*CR) and (*ANY)](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#pcre) to override the default behavior of the $ anchor, but not in Python.

Comment: That really sucks in Python then I think, only supporting "Linux-style" linebreaks, even when executed on Windows, and also not being able to override this behavior, like in PCRE. :-(

Answer (score 1):

A hack, but...

```
re.findall(r'//.*?(?=\r|\n|(?!.))', input, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

This should replicate the behaviour of the default `$` anchor (just before `\r`, `\n` or end of string).

Comment: Why do you use `(?!.)`? Is it `\Z` (the unambiguous end of string)?

Comment: @stribizhev haha yeah. Yours is definitely more more thought through :D

Comment: I am fond of workarounds myself, but in this case, we can just use built-in means, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you also could use `\v` *vertical space* which would match `[\n\cK\f\r\x85\x{2028}\x{2029}]`

To not include it into the output use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `//.*(?=\v|$)`

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zA6xS1/2)